# ListView CheckBox not returning checked object

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a listview object and in the object properties, i have "Checkbox" set to true.

Listviewitems are dynamically added and tagged with an object.

If during selection, I check the checkbox, no object is returned. But if i click on the listviewitem itself, the tagged object gets returned. What am i missing ?

Comment: @StepUp this is winforms.

Comment: "no object is returned",  can you provide the code here you get the "selected" items?

Comment: What do you mean when you say  "no object is returned"? By click on items or checkboxes nothing returns.

Comment: @BrunoJoaquim I just edited please see update

Comment: @RezaAghaei if i click on items, i can get the object. But i want users to click on the checkbox instead so i could retrieve the object from there.

Comment: Where do you use `getDoc`?

Comment: @RezaAghaei in an OK button click event.

Comment: Do you mean you want to select Item when you click on checkbox?

Comment: @RezaAghaei yes thats what i need.

Comment: When you [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer, it would be great if you kindly vote for answer too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select or deselect items by click on checkbox, you can handle [`Itemchecked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemchecked(v=vs.110).aspx) event and set the value of `Selected` property of item to value of `Checked`:

```
private void listView1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Item.Selected = e.Item.Checked;
}
```